# Use case of dummy operator in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

I was learning Apache Airflow and found that there is an operator called `DummyOperator`. I googled about its use case, but couldn't find anything that I can understand. Can anyone here please discuss its use case along with some example code?

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? I came here because I asked myself the same thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Operator that does literally nothing. It can be used to group tasks in
> a DAG.

https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/operators/dummy_operator/index.html

As far as I know, at least two use case:

- test purpose: in DAGs, the dummy operation is just between upstream and
  downstream, later, you can replace the true operator.
- Workflow purpose: `BranchPythonOperator` works with `DummyOperator`. If you want to skip some tasks, keep in mind that you can’t have an
  empty path, if so make a **dummy task**.
  https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#workflows

Comment: adding another use-case here: if you have a set of 'd' downstream tasks that must all execute after 'u' upstream tasks, then rather than creating a 'mesh' of 'u x d' connections in between, you can introduce a `dummyoperator` in between these two sets of tasks and get away with 'u + d' connections. This certainly provides an aesthetic improvement in rendering of your DAG (looks simpler, lighter to render), but can also potentially decrease the scheduling overhead (and scheduler latency) since much lesser number of conditions have to be evaluated to check scheduling-ready state

Comment: @Yong Wang how can I keep some latency between two tasks ...i.e. after first task successful wait 1 hr and start second task.......how to check how my first job executed with shellscript is success or not ?

Comment: @BdEngineer Thanks for question. As far as I think the most convenient mode is to create a bashoperator  which sleet  1hour'. And  add it between the upstream task and downstream task. In this way, the original downstream task will be delay 1 hour after original upsteam task successed.. Hope it help you.

Comment: @y2k-shubham  vote for the sense of  aesthetic. Clean and elegant way.

Answer (score 7):

`dummy_operator` is used in `BranchPythonOperator` where we decide the next task based on some condition.

For example:

```
                  -> task C->task D

 task A -> task B                      -> task F
                   ->  task E(Dummy)
```

So let's suppose we have some condition in task B that decides whether to follow [task C->task D] or task E(Dummy) to reach task F.

Since we cannot leave else condition empty we have to put a dummy operator which does nothing just skip or bypass.

Comment: Why can't the condition create a dependency directly from `task B` to `task F`?

Answer (score 2):

Another use case:

I've implemented a framework that returns an Operator. In most cases this is a `PostgresOperator` but under some user-specified configuration there's no SQL to run but the caller still expects an Operator, so I return a `DummyOperator` rather than a `PostgresOperator` with trivial SQL like "`select 1;`".